# How to generate PDF using Angular15 without changing HTML structure

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with Angular15. But I am facing issue while generation PDF.

**Scenario:** As per requirement I need to generate PDF when user clicks on Download PDF button. The content is coming from reusable component. In this case I have two components called “cartpage” and “cartlistpage”. The cartlistpage component was designed as reusable way for future use. In this cartlist page we are displaying list of items added to the cart. We added cartlistpage component in “cartpage” to display the list of items.In this cartpage we have “welcome Cart” text and download PDF button.

**Problem:** When I click download PDF button, I can generate PDF successfully. But I am not able to print the “Welcome Cart” text along with “items”. As per client request, I want to generate PDF with “welcome cart” text and list of items. No need to display button without changing the HTML structure.

**Note:** i tried to reproduce my senario with example data.

**cartlistpage.component.html**  This component is reusable component. In this HTML we are displaying dynamic content.

```
<p>Content for PDF Content for PDF  Content for PDF  Content for PDF  Content for PDF </p>
```

**cartpage.component.html** In this we are adding cartlist page and download button as below.

```
<div class="cart-container">
  <div class="cart-content">
    <div class="cart-header" id="pdfPreview1">Welcome to Cart</div>
    <div class="cart-actions">
      <div class="printer">
        <button (click)="downloadPDF()">Download PDF</button>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <app-cartlistpage></app-cartlistpage>
  </div>   
</div>
```

**cartpage.component.scss**

```
.cart-container{
    display: block;
    justify-content:center;
    .cart-content{
        .cart-header{
            display: flex;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 700;
            width: 55%;
            .cart-actions{
                display: flex;
                justify-content: flex-end;
                width: 45%;
                gap:2rem;
                .printer{
                    display: flex;
                    align-self: start;
                    align-items: center;
                    gap:0.5rem;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**cartpage.component.ts** In this .ts file we wrote a code for generating PDF.
**Note:** Used "html2canvas" and "jspdf" packages for PDF creation.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cartpage',
  templateUrl: './cartpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cartpage.component.scss'],
})
export class CartpageComponent {
  downloadPDF() {
    let data = document.getElementById('pdfPreview1');
    if (data != null) {
      html2canvas(data).then(
        (res: { toDataURL: (arg0: string, arg1: number) => any }) => {
          const URL = res.toDataURL('image/JPEG', 1.0);
          let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'cm', 'a4');
          pdf.addImage(URL, 'PNG', 1, 1, 19, 15);
          pdf.save('PrintcartItems.pdf');
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

I want to display "Welcome Cart" header and "cartlist in PDF.

I tried to give pdfPreview ID in cartlist component. But it is displaying only cartlist data. If i added it in cartpage it is displaying only cartpage "welcome Cart" ad PDF.

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: If you can get away with it I recommend `window.print()` and styling `@media print { @page { size: A4; margin: 0; }}` etc. and you can hide things with `display: none` inside the print media query.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Allen, Thanks for the suggestion. But we already have Print option in same page. User wants PDF only.

Comment: seems like everything that's going into the PDF should be nested inside this element:  <div class="cart-header" id="pdfPreview1">Welcome to Cart</div> If I'm reading your posted code correctly, only "Welcome to Cart" will be in your generated PDF file.

Comment: @pcalkins hi yes "Welcome to cart" only it is displaying. But i want both "welcome cart" and "content for PDF" also without downloadpdf button.

Comment: Whatever you want in the PDF file should be inside that DIV.

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty way could be to create a new element, append elements you want to print, add it to the document, and then remove after printing is done.

For example, declare template variable for *welcome* element, send it via the method, and then append it to the temp element, as well as the main pdf content of the cartlist component, print and then remove:

template:

```
  <!-- welcome element -->
  <div class="cart-header" #welcome>Welcome to Cart</div>
  <div class="cart-actions">
    <div class="printer">
      <!-- send welcome -->
      <button (click)="downloadPDF(welcome)">Download PDF</button>        
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- content to print -->
  <app-cartlistpage id="pdfPreview1"></app-cartlistpage>
```

component:

```
  public downloadPDF(welcome: HTMLElement) {

    var data = document.getElementById('pdfPreview1');

    if (data != null) {

      // construct pdf from desired elements
      const tempEl = document.createElement('div');
      tempEl.innerHTML = welcome.outerHTML + data.innerHTML;
      // use some hack to hide the duplicate element to make UX better..
      tempEl.style.cssText = 'position:fixed;bottom:-999999px;';
      // append to the DOM
      data.appendChild(tempEl);

      html2canvas(tempEl).then(
        (res: { toDataURL: (arg0: string, arg1: number) => any }) => {
          const URL = res.toDataURL('image/JPEG', 1.0);
          let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'cm', 'a4');
          pdf.addImage(URL, 'PNG', 1, 1, 19, 15);
          pdf.save('PrintcartItems.pdf');
          // remove
          tempEl.remove();
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

(future refactoring could include referencing elements you need via `Input` or `ViewChild`)

For example:

```
  @ViewChild('welcome') welcome: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild(CartlistpageComponent, {read: ElementRef}) data: ElementRef;
```

and then

```
  tempEl.innerHTML = this.welcome.nativeElement.outerHTML + this.data.nativeElement.innerHTML;
```